# Azure Machine Learning integration of R: Should the 'azureml' module have an attribute 'core'?

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, rstudio, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm having issues with Azure Machine Learning SDK for R: "module 'azureml' has no attribute 'core'"...

For reasons that aren't my own, I have to use azureml to apply machine learning (my own stuff, written in R) to data from our data warehouse that is put in the blob storage. The modelled output should be put back into the blob storage so it can be accessed from the data warehouse.
I've written the code in R on my local machine (stored in a git repo). Preferably, I'd find some method to pull my code from git into a pipeline in the azureml environment so that it can be directly run whenever new data is available in the blob storage.

I've embarked on a tutorial-spree and found this seemingly relevant walkthrough: [Train and deploy your first model with Azure ML](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/#getting-started) (and [this one](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/train-and-deploy-to-aci/train-and-deploy-to-aci.html)).

But... after trying all I could think of, I'm stuck on the first steps. After installing all (or at least.. that's what I think) packages, modules, apps etc, and running the following code in RStudio:

```
   library(azuremlsdk)
    existing_ws <- get_workspace(name = name, 
                                 subscription_id = subscription_id, 
                                 resource_group)
```

I run into an error that I haven't been able to fix:

> AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute 'core'

It seems that the azuerml is supposed to have an attribute "core", but when looking at it more closely, there is indeed no such attribute. 
The function "get_workspace()" is trying to access: "azureml$core$Workspace$get".
I found that "azuerML$Workspace" does exist, but then I can't figure out how to make that work.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm encountering this error?
Does anyone know of a better tutorial on how to connect my R code the azureml's cloud service?

Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated!

---

EDITS - still not solved:
After advice from others, I double, triple and quadruple checked the [installation](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html).

I updated R and I'm now running:

> R.version
>
> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          6.2
>   year           2019
>   month          12
>   day            12
>   svn rev        77560
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
>   nickname       Dark and Stormy Night

I installed [Conda](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html#install-conda) with Python 3.6.10.
I installed [the azuremlsdk R package](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html#install-the-azuremlsdk-r-package) (I tried both provided options).
I then realized that there are some inconsistencies with the versions of the azure-modules, so I also tried installing it with the keyword 'multi-arch':

```
remotes::install_cran('azuremlsdk', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))
```

Then, I [installed the azureml python sdk](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html#install-the-azure-ml-python-sdk).
I had a look at all the versions again (using python -m pip freeze):

> azure-common==1.1.24
>
> azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
>
> azure-mgmt-authorization==0.60.0
>
> azure-mgmt-containerregistry==2.8.0
>
> azure-mgmt-keyvault==2.0.0
>
> azure-mgmt-resource==7.0.0
>
> azure-mgmt-storage==7.1.0
>
> azureml==0.2.7
>
> azureml-automl-core==1.0.83.1
>
> azureml-core==1.0.69
>
> azureml-dataprep==1.1.36
>
> azureml-dataprep-native==13.2.0
>
> azureml-pipeline==1.0.69
>
> azureml-pipeline-core==1.0.69
>
> azureml-pipeline-steps==1.0.69
>
> azureml-sdk==1.0.69
>
> azureml-telemetry==1.0.69
>
> azureml-train==1.0.69
>
> azureml-train-automl-client==1.0.83
>
> azureml-train-core==1.0.69
>
> azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive==1.0.69

As I was surprised to see all the 1.0.69 versions, instead of the 1.0.83 versions, I re-installed the azureml python sdk using:

```
azuremlsdk::install_azureml(version = "1.0.83")
```

This worked, in the sense that indeed all versions are now 1.0.83:

> azure-common==1.1.24
>
> azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
>
> azure-mgmt-authorization==0.60.0
>
> azure-mgmt-containerregistry==2.8.0
>
> azure-mgmt-keyvault==2.0.0
>
> azure-mgmt-resource==7.0.0
>
> azure-mgmt-storage==7.1.0
>
> azureml==0.2.7
>
> azureml-automl-core==1.0.83.1
>
> azureml-core==1.0.83
>
> azureml-dataprep==1.1.36
>
> azureml-dataprep-native==13.2.0
>
> azureml-pipeline==1.0.83
>
> azureml-pipeline-core==1.0.83
>
> azureml-pipeline-steps==1.0.83
>
> azureml-sdk==1.0.83
>
> azureml-telemetry==1.0.83
>
> azureml-train==1.0.83
>
> azureml-train-automl-client==1.0.83
>
> azureml-train-core==1.0.83
>
> azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive==1.0.83

But still... I get the error with the missing core. I get it both when running:

```
library(azuremlsdk)
get_current_run()
```

and also when running:

```
library(azuremlsdk)
existing_ws <- get_workspace(name = name, 
                         subscription_id = subscription_id, 
                         resource_group)
```

Note that the first time running this code after starting up RStudio, I get the error:

> Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
>     AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute '_base_sdk_common'

And every time after that I get this error:

> Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
>     AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute 'core'

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be that `azuremlsdk` is not yet fully installed? In the GitHub instructions for installation, the package author mentions that the package needs to install the compiled code from the AzureML Python SDK using `azuremlsdk::install_azureml()` before creating/getting a workspace: https://github.com/Azure/azureml-sdk-for-r

Comment: I followed the following steps in R:

install.packages("azuremlsdk")

remotes::install_github('https://github.com/Azure/azureml-sdk-for-r')

azuremlsdk::install_azureml()
--> it ended with the message "Installation complete"

After starting up R again, I got a new error:
"AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute '_base_sdk_common'Error in value[[3L]](cond) : "

But after (re-)installing azuremlsdk, I still got the old error again:
"AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute '_base_sdk_common'Error in value[[3L]](cond) : "

Comment: That's a python error. Are you running this within a conda environment? Perhaps you could try the installation instructions here: https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html

Comment: Note that you need to EITHER do `install.packages` which means you are installing the package from CRAN, OR `remotes::install_github` which means you are installing from Github. You don't need to do both.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. But after installing it with the first method, it didn't work, so I also tried installing it with the second method, which also didn't work...
Thanks for the link. I'll go through those steps now.

Comment: So after following those steps, I get the following error when running "Test installation":
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute 'core'

Comment: https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html#test-installation

Comment: Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'azureml' has no attribute 'core'

Comment: This is so weird, I don't know what's going on! Perhaps you should post an issue in the GitHub for this package and the author/maintainer can help figure this out.

Comment: Ok.. I also have no clue where to find the solution. I'll also ask it on their github page. Thanks for having a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help further. I followed the installation instructions from scratch too, and when I work through the "test installation" step, I get a successful return telling me I'm offline. `library(azuremlsdk)
get_current_run()
<azureml.core.run._OfflineRun>`

Answer (score 1):

This issue was introduced by the latest reticulate 1.14 release, in which reticulate would create a default `r-reticulate` conda environment. Since Azure ML was installing the python SDK in an environment named `r-azureml`, the `r-reticulate` environment used by reticulate was missing the python SDK. A fix for this issue was addressed in a [PR](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-sdk-for-r/pull/221) and has been merged into master. Please install from GitHub for now if you have reticulate version 1.14 and are running into this issue. We will be releasing an update to CRAN shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed the issue by specifically installing the python package azureml AND azureml.core:

`python -m pip install azureml`

and then...

`python -m pip install azureml.core`

I did this for the Conda version that was called by R (r-reticulate). It's a bit odd to not be able to use the Conda environment 'r-azureml' without R switching back to 'r-reticulate', but ah well... at least I don't get my 'azureml' has no attribute 'core' anymore.